# Open Graph crawler not waiting for React component mounting

Tags: reactjs, facebook-opengraph, react-helmet

The issue we are facing has to do with the meta tags being populated on individual pages. This is a common problem with single-page sites, but is exacerbated in our case due to the face that we do server side rendering of a chunk of our site for the initial load, and the rest is done asynchronously on the front end. Because of this, Facebook is interpreting the og tags from the initial load as the end-all tags and isn't waiting for further components to mount, which would change the meta tags with the use of Helmet.

If a page is loaded up in a browser and then inspected, the correct tags are being shown, but when scanned with Facebook, it's only getting the initial load set of tags.

Any suggestions for how to address this issue would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Any update on this? Did you find a solution?